# Changing <object> height and width works in Chrome but not Firefox or IE. Why?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, object, google-chrome

I am making a site with two Youtube videos. These videos use the raw embed code from Youtube. The site's design doesn't work with any of the default Youtube sizes, so I am writing code to automatically resize the video.  Here is my code.  There will never be more than these two  tags on the page, otherwise I'd do a better job selecting the videos.

```
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
var x=document.getElementsByTagName('object');

x.[0].width='350';
x.[0].height='350';
x.[1].width='350';
x.[1].height='350';

</script>
```

For reference, here's a sample default Youtube embed that the code might alter:

```
<object width="480" height="385">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/zSgiXGELjbc&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/zSgiXGELjbc&hl=en_US&fs=1&rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

In Chrome, the video players sit perfectly in a 350x350 box. In IE and FF (latest versions), the videos are the unchanged, normal size.  I cannot find anything in Google that explans why this won't work.  I have tried using setattribute, for loops, adjusting both  and , single-quotes and double-quotes, etc.

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firefox uses the values in the 'embed' not just values the 'object' tag - probably need to replace both to be sure

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to to write `x[0]` not `x.[0]`.
If that doesn't work, too, i've got two more ideas:

(1)

```
x[0].width='350px';
x[0].height='350px';
x[1].width='350px';
x[1].height='350px';
```

(2)

```
x[0].style.width='350px';
x[0].style.height='350px';
x[1].style.width='350px';
x[1].style.height='350px';
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but none of those made any difference.  This is very perplexing.

Comment: Does anybody else have an idea?  I am still trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It's `x[0].style.width`.

width, height, display, etc.are all properties of the object's style.

And I write `x[0].style.width = 350 + px`

Also notice that both your object and your embed have inline-specified dimensions, and those might override your JS, depending on the browser/version.