# set the width of an embedded youtube video

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have created a custom made videogallery of my own. It can display html5 videos and youtube videos. The videos load dynamically , depending on what user clicked.

At first I have

```
var elemv = document.createElement("video");
elemv.setAttribute("width", "70%");
elemv.setAttribute("controls", "true");
elemv.setAttribute("type","application/x-shockwave-flash");
```

Then, I use websockets to bring the paths of the videos from the database. I create an array with them. When the user clicks "next" for example, I load the next array item in a div

```
//if html5 video

    {document.getElementById("videogal").innerHTML=' ';
           //get the next source and then load it
         elemv.src=mplv[i];
        document.getElementById("videogal").appendChild(elemv);     
        }

//if youtube link

     document.getElementById("videogal").innerHTML='<object id="viewer" >'+mplv[i]+'</object>';
```

That's makes it possible to have youtube and html5 videos in the same gallery. All the youtube links are like `<iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/LIS2uZ8a9YQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`. Width is always `640`

*The problem:*

At the beggingn of my code I set `"width", "70%"`. This works only for the html5 videos, Any suggestions on how to make it work for the youtube videos?

I tried 
`document.getElementById("videogal").innerHTML='<object id="viewer" width= "70%;" >'+mplv[i]+'</object>';`

(added width), but does not work.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you inspected the element to see if the width is being applied or disregarded?

Comment: @user2954995 Firebug says width is 70%. According to this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680409/changing-object-height-and-width-works-in-chrome-but-not-firefox-or-ie-why` I have to set `width="70%"` inside the `<iframe>` code. And it works. Resizes with the screen. I want his for responsive design. But still does not look good aesthetically. So, is there a guide of something to create thumbs from youtube? Happen to know ? Thanks

Comment: @user2954995 Also, about my original question Chrome says `The value "device-width" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored`. Its there as an error and I cannot click it so I can go to the right place of code...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a "flexible" width to achieve responsive design in all the devices and browsers.

Apparently, adding `class="youtube-player" type="text/html"` in my `<iframe>` code will do the trick. It will use html5 or fallback to flash and it will modify the video according to the viewing environment. Check [this](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html) out.

Then , why when I'm in youtube, and  I click "embed" under a video, the `iframe` code does not contain this : `class="youtube-player" type="text/html"` ? If is so "magic" why is not there by defualt And I have to add it? Anyway.....